# Getting the bowl out of the mold

Tags: baking, cake

This is the "[Cook's Choice, Better Baker Edible Bowl Maker](http://www.cookschoice.com/store/better-bakers/better-baker-3/)" which I received as a gift.

[image]

Now the idea appears clever enough, but everything I try to do with it either comes out too hard to be enjoyable (not 'Good Eats') or it comes out like this: (the finished product won't come out in one usable piece.

[image]

I've greased/floured the bowls, I've allowed the product to cool thoroughly...

What techniques or recipe adjustments will help me get a usable cake out of the mold?
*(note: I would also like to be able to use this for breads, but I'll settle for getting a usable cake out of the mold for now...)*

**[Follow-up]:** *With thanks to all who contributed..*

So I found some Pam Baking spray (yea, right next to the stuff I always get, just hadn't noticed it before...) and tried releasing the cakes before they were fully cooled:
[image: Add a shot of rum, some pecans and caramel...mmmm.]

Comment: Have you tried non stick cake spray?

Comment: You might try breads first. In my experience they have more crust and more structure overall so they are easier to get out of containers in one piece.

Comment: I've tried both, I just have ideas I would like to explore with cake. (think-caramel-pecan-rum cakes...)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, just to clarify I have tried Non-stick spray; Is there a "non-stick **cake** spray" that is particularly effective for cakes?

Comment: @CosCallis there are baking non-stick sprays which contain flour... Common US brands include Baker's Joy.

Comment: @derobert, have you found these to be 'better' than 'regular' spray + flour?

Comment: I've never tested the difference. Though I think I'd give it a try, before my next idea, which would be to somehow get parchment between the pan and the batter... I'm confident the parchment will work, and also confident it looks like a PITA to do. (I've never used a pan like that.)

Comment: Can't hurt to try it. Thanks to both derobert and ElendilTheTall. (yeah, thought about parchment paper...just looks like too much trouble...)

Comment: Not all cakes want a floured pan. My favorite hazelnut torte requires a well-greased pan (with unsalted butter, preferably), but not a speck of flour. In any case, more fat might be the answer: put on twice as much butter as you think is sufficient, then double it. Also, did the pan itself come with any recipes? Those might be optimized for better releasing vs. a traditional cake. And as others have said, *don't* wait for the cake to cool completely: give it a few minutes to set after coming out of the oven, and then turn it onto a rack.

Comment: I would go with the bread suggestion, plus other pastries. Gluten is what holds doughs together, so if anything has a chance to get out of these whole, it is high-gluten. Cakes are supposed to be tender, they don't have much internal cohesion if they are good. There you face a trade-off: the better the cake, the harder to get it out. For sweet creations, try shells out of danish pastry or millefeuille. They will all release much easier than cakes. Another option to explore would be to find the same pan but with silicone molds within the sheet, it would work with cakes then.

Comment: @rumtscho To clarify, gluten holds kneaded or long resting yeast doughs together.  Most muffins, quick breads, and cakes have very little gluten development, and their structure is based on a foam of gelatized starch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for recipes for 'cake release', which is typically a mixture of equal parts solid shortening, flour and oil.  You can then paint it on with a pastry brush.

You also don't always want items to cool fully before removing from the pan; you might need to warm the pan back up some for the item to release.

Answer (score 4):

While it is not traditional, I have had excellent success with cakes, breads, and muffins by liberally spraying with spray oil.  I use my store brand's grapeseed oil, but any will do.  I use the kind *without* additional flour.

An additional advantage is it is very easy to do individual cups or molds with the spray.

I usually do my spraying over the sink to save mess on any overspray.  A tip I have read is to do it over the open door of your dishwasher for the same reason.

Comment: I like to grease with butter - same basic idea, my theory is that butter has more flavour and doesn't bead very easily. It does burn, but the dish is rarely in the oven long enough for that...

Comment: So true, I used to do that.  I use the spray oil for laziness.

Answer (score 1):

Your pans look like they're "non-stick".  Did the pans come with any directions on whether they need to be greased (probably different instructions for cakes and breads) or "seasoned" first?

1. Follow the manufacturer's instructions regarding greasing or prepping the pan
2. I would do is what is recommended on many US **cake** product packaging: cool the pan for 10 minutes
3. Use a pointy knife to carefully ease any sticky parts of the cake from the pan.  It's not a cutting motion (you don't want to scratch the pan), but rather a gently finessed motion around the inner edge of the individual cups
4. When you can gently wiggle the top of the cup (the part that is sticking up from the pan, GENTLY try to lift the cake.  If you feel resistance, repeat the knife routine

Comment: To release around the edges, I like either a really narrow blade (I use a boning knife) or a plastic knife so I don't scratch the surface for non-stick pans.  Once you've gone around, you can sometimes use the knife to press inward at various points to get it to release from the bottom ... but I don't know how well it'll work with this mold.

Comment: @Joe, thanks for the input but I have already tried this approach. The clinging appears to be happening on the bottom and along the center post.

Comment: @CosCallis : try a solid fat (or blend, like cake release), bake it, let it cool some, then take a torch to warm up the post in the middle, and see if that'll get it to release.  (once the fat cools, it stick again, so we need it liquid when it's time to release)

Comment: @CosCallis, Joe's point about the fat being still more liquid than cooled in order to release from the pan is a good one.